# Low LDO output capacitance (stability)

Tags: capacitance, output, ldo, stability, dropout

I need to replace the [REG104](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/reg104.pdf?ts=1702510481198) LDO (End of life) in a circuit where the max. allowed LDO output capacitance is 100 nF because of explosion proof intrinsic safety requirements. The REG104 LDO is stable without any output capacitance and still provides a very low dropout voltage.

I have the following questions:

1. Which (internal properties) define the stability of a LDO linear regulator? How is the (low) dropout voltage related to output capacitance?
2. Is there a way to stabilize an LDO with e.g. 1 μF requirement with only 0.1 μF? (e.g. capacitor multiplier circuit?)
3. Although this is not a product recommendation forum: Are there other LDO's with low output capacitor requirements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LDOs are feedback systems, so their stability depends on open loop gain: output voltage -> error voltage on FB pin -> internal error amp -> pass device -> output voltage.

The classic positive LDO architecture uses a PMOS pass element ([TPS7A24](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a24.pdf)):

[image]

The PMOS is wired in common source, so it acts like a voltage controlled current source. The output cap integrates this current, which creates a pole (usually the dominant one). This means open loop gain is directly proportional to the value of the output cap. For stability you want good phase margin when gain reaches zero, which sets a condition on the cap -- if it is too small, gain will be too high, so it will fall to zero at a higher frequency where other poles will add too much phase lag.

Your [REG104](https://www.ti.com/product/REG104?keyMatch=REG104&tisearch=search-everything&usecase=GPN) LDO uses a NMOS as a follower:

[image]

This creates a different open loop response. In the PMOS case, all control of the output has to go through the error amp, whereas in the NMOS case if the error amp  has low output impedance and ground referenced compensation, the NMOS will act as a follower up to high frequency and handle part of the regulation all by itself.

This creates a fast inner loop which makes transient response much faster, and more relevant to your case, the output is no longer a current source but rather a voltage source with some impedance. It does not rely on the output cap as integrator to form a dominant pole.

In the PMOS case, a larger output cap will simply lower open loop gain and shift the dominant pole down in frequency, which makes it more stable. So it has a **minimum** capacitor value but no maximum.

In the NMOS case, the dominant pole is formed in the internal compensation of the error amp, and the output cap adds a secondary pole. This one should not be too low in frequency, so these LDOs usually have a **maximum** capacitance requirement, quoting REG104:

> None of the versions require an output capacitor for regulator stability. The REG104 will accept any output capacitor type less than 1µF. For capacitance values larger than 1µF the effective ESR should be greater than 0.1Ω.

So if the cap is too large, it requires ESR to create a zero to compensate for the capacitor pole. You could say the PMOS LDO works because of the output cap, while the NMOS LDO works in spite of the output cap.

NMOS offers lower output impedance, faster transient response, needs lower output capacitance, but at the cost of a more complicated and expensive chip: it needs a charge pump to drive the gate above output voltage, which also uses more power and could make some noise.

Anyway, TI has a "minimum capacitance value" column in its LDO search engine so you should use that. They also suggest some replacements for REG101 (not REG104).

https://www.ti.com/product/TPS731

AD has an "[AnyCap](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adp3309.pdf)" line of LDOs which use P (in this case PNP) with some clever compensation to use a low output cap.

It's possible to synthetize an output impedance that looks like a N follower with a P, but that needs a faster chip (more expensive, uses more power) and it falls apart at low dropout when the PMOS gets squeezed between input and output and becomes extremely slow.

> Is there a way to stabilize an LDO with e.g. 1uF requirement with only 0.1uF? (e.g. capacitor multiplier circuit?)

You could use the adjustable version and add a cap in the feedback network to "emulate" the frequency effect of the larger output cap, but I have no idea if this will guarantee stability in all conditions. Open loop gain strongly depends on output current (because FET Gm is proportional to current) and dropout voltage, so you'd have to validate it across a lot of operating points.

I guess the point of having low capacitance is to waste minimum energy when switching it on/off (energy stored in the cap is lost at the end). You could also use a micropower LDO with a large output cap and a switch after.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The point of having low capacitance in my case is explosion proof intrinsic safety.

Comment: OK, so no sparks allowed? How much output current do you need? TI recommends a replacement for smaller REG101 but not REG104

Comment: I need 150mA at max. 350mV drop. Thanks for the TPS731 info, but another requirement is that I need Vin max. of 16V (and the TPS731 only provides 6V). It seems to me that TI just wants to get their Burr-Brown REG104 customers into trouble?

Comment: So your Vin is 3.65V--16V? No higher voltage available anywhere? I guess REG104 was a victim of cheap ceramic caps and new improved PMOS LDOs...

Answer (score 3):

> Which (internal properties) define the stability of a LDO linear regulator? How is the (low) dropout voltage related to output capacitance?

An LDO is still a linear regulator but the series-pass element in an LDO is a P-type transistor (PMOS or PNP BJT). This allows you to control the series pass element with voltages much lower than the input voltage.

But since the output is taken from the collector or the drain which has inherently high output impedance, when combined with an output capacitance it'll introduce a pole (There are other internal poles coming from the regulator design). Every pole brings a phase lag therefore reduces the phase margin. Introducing more poles brings more phase lag, and once the phase reaches -180° and there you go, you'll have an oscillator!

> Is there a way to stabilize an LDO with e.g. 1uF requirement with only 0.1uF? (e.g. capacitor multiplier circuit?)

Well, you'll need to introduce a zero to compensate the pole(s)'s effect. The easiest way is to place a series RC across the load. So a capacitor with high ESR (or generally, a capacitor with series resistor) may help. This will have effect on dynamic response, though.

> Although this is not a product recommendation forum: Are there other LDO's with low output capacitor requirements?

Must be, although it can be difficult due to the requirement of internal compensation.

Answer (score 2):

1. LDOs have the output connected to the collector or the drain of the pass transistor, a relatively high impedance node. Output capacitance forms a pole with the output impedance || load, which affects stability of the closed-loop system. Aside from stability, to get good load regulation you also generally need a large output capacitor.
2. Possibly, at least over some range of load current you could have a something like a BJT with the base fed by a high-pass filter and some bias. You'd have to test and simulate it over a range of conditions.
3. If you have a higher voltage rail available you could consider a linear regulator controller, which would use a discrete drain/emitter output pass device. There are also semi-low dropout parts such as the LT3088 (1.21V dropout at 100mA) which do not require capacitors for stability.

I presume the 100nF requirement is for intrinsic safety, and searching for that term may yield additional options.